# Replacing Storybook's DocsPage with my .mdx file

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, storybook

I want to change my stories' Docs page, so when I click on Canvas, it shows the component and props from the story.js file, and when I click on Docs it shows me my self-made MDX file instead of the autogenerated one.

This is what the documentation says:

[image]

The page parameter looks like this:

```
parameters: {
  docs: {
    page: null
  }
}
```

I set it to null, so now it shows nothing.
Does anyone know what value I should give the `page` to use my `x.stories.mdx` named file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Original Answer

I'm not sure how it works by changing things in the parameters.

But what I do is, this in main.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  // ...
};
```

And then just add the `x.stories.mdx` in that location:

```
import {Meta} from '@storybook/addon-docs';

<Meta title="Info/Toolbox"/> <!-- This notation creates a subtitle -->

Your documentation here ...
```

This is what my `docs` looks like in parameters:

```js
docs: { inlineStories: true }
```

### Update

I found that you can use the docs object in parameters to change for example component & story descriptions. e.g.:

```
docs: {
  description: {
    component: 'Some component description',
    story: 'Some story description'
  }
}
```

You can actually link files to these, if you want the description to be in some text file. But it is **not meant to set an mdx file replacing the documentation**.

The mdx file is supposed to be picked up like I described in the original answer.

I think the confusion is that you can't create documentation for just the **docs** tab. You actually create documentation for **both Canvas and Docs** using MDX.

I recently made an MDX version approximating the autogenerated documentation of a simple component in a project of mine, maybe it can help you out with yours.

You can find the MDX code [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/H3AR7B3A7/Toolbox/master/toolbox-fe/src/app/core/nav-bar/nav-bar.stories.mdx),
and the storybook server [here](https://6317ba136ba081048e962a53-jqdpcpgvbv.chromatic.com/?path=/story/home-page-mdx-navbar--default-story).

*You will find there is a HOME PAGE and a HOME PAGE (MDX) section.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have the same setup, my .mdx files are displayed correctly.
I have tried the `docs: { inlineStories: true }` option, but did not help. I also tried to give a relative path to the `docs.page`, but it gives me an error.

Comment: @Mortenz Maybe add that error to your question. I will try to help.

Comment: So I contacted the storybook team, and I was told that the documentation on this one, `Replacing Storybook's DocsPage` is a bit misleading and I should use the documentation for `MDX` instead. So basically, it is still not clear to me how I could set up the Canvas  (story.js) + Docs (my .mdx) setup.

Comment: @Mortenz I just updated my answer because I looked at the problem more closely and managed to recreate StoryBook Documentation using the MDX approach. I added a link to a project where I approximated the auto generated docs. Cheers